# Searching for semicolon inside a string in batch causes weird issues

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to write a simple batch command that reads the second line of a file (ProfileName), looks for a ";" in that line and then splits the line and stores it in two variables (ProfileName and RRSProfileName)

```
    for /F "tokens=1 skip=1" %%A in (%ContentFilePath%) do ( SET ProfileName=%%A )
    ECHO %ProfileName% | findstr /spin ";">nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
         FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ("%ProfileName%") do ( SET ProfileName=%%A& SET RRSProfileName=%%B ) 
    )
```

ContentFile contains 2 lines

```
    blah
    blah1
```

For some reason, ProfileName variable does not get set if the "IF" statement is present. If I remove the "IF" statement, ProfileName gets set to blah1. This is bizzare. Can someone help?  Both ProfileName and RRSProfileName are set to "" initially.

Comment: Are you executing this within a loop?  You will need delayed expansion if that is the case, or use `IF not ERRORLEVEL 1 (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /spin
```

it search in subdirectories (`/s`) omitting non printable files (`/p`) ignoring case (`/i`) numbering output lines (`/n`), and you are not giving any file, so `findstr` fails as its arguments are not correct. From here you get errorlevel 1, so, the code inside the `if` is not executed

Better use

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1 skip=1" %%A in ("%ContentFilePath%") do ( SET "ProfileName=%%A" )
ECHO %ProfileName%| find ";" > nul 
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
     FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ("%ProfileName%") do ( SET "ProfileName=%%A" & SET "RRSProfileName=%%B" ) 
)
```

Or just (if it is possible, i don't know all your cases), join the two steps into one

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=;" %%a in ("%ContentFilePath%"
) do ( set "ProfileName=%%a" & set "RRSProfileName=%%b" )
```

It reads the same required line, if semicolon is present, it is used to split the line and each of the variables retrieve the required content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this syntax (joining 2 steps) earlier and for some reason when there was no semicolon, I used to get RRSProfileName set to %B instead of "". This was causing problems. However I cannot repro this anymore. RRSProfileName gets set to "" when there is no semicolon and that helps with further operations in the batch

Answer (score 1):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1delims=;" %%A in (q22602116.txt) do SET "ProfileName=%%A"&SET "RRSProfileName=%%B"
```

worked perfectly well for me, assuming that `Profilename` should be set to the portion before the semicolon on the last line and `RRSprofilename` to the portion after (if it exists)

But - be careful of the presence of <kbd>Spaces</kbd> in a string-assignment - they are significant (original batch appeared to have trailing spaces...) - the quotes positioned just so should overcome this characteristic...